# Get specific value from JSON to PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to get specific value from json . IF ID main is true and Label value Money Line or Total Points or Point Spread get there outcome   line and oddsAmerican  value . please let me know where i am wrong . json is giving too many id without main true.

```
<?php $url = 'https://iakshay.website/test/demo.json';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$characters = json_decode($data, true);
?>

<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Date/Time</th>
        <th>Games</th>
        <th>Spread</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>Moneyline</th>

    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($characters['events'] as $events) {
        $str = $events['startDate'];
        $actdate = explode("T", $str);
        $row = '';
                $row .= '<tr><td>' . $actdate[0] . '</td><td>' . $events["name"] . '</td>';

        foreach ($events['offers'] as $offers) {
            if ($offers['main']==true || $offers['main']==1) {

                if (\strcasecmp($offers['label'], "Point Spread") === 0) {
                    $line = $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican = $offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';
                    $line2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['line'] ?? 'No Data';
                    $oddsAmerican2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';

                    $row .= "<td>$line ($oddsAmerican) </br> $line2 ($oddsAmerican2)</td>";

                } else {
                    $row .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
                }

                if (\strcasecmp($offers['label'], "Total Points") === 0) {
                    $line = $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican = $offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';
                    $line2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['line'] ?? '';
                    $oddsAmerican2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['oddsAmerican'] ?? '';

                    $row .= "<td>$line ($oddsAmerican) </br> $line2 ($oddsAmerican2)</td>";

                } else {
                    $row .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
                }

                if (\strcasecmp($offers['label'], "Money line") === 0) {
                    $line = $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'] ?? '';
                     $line2 = $offers['outcomes'][1]['line'] ?? '';

                    $row .= "<td>$line  </br> $line2</td>";

                } else {
                    $row .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
                }

                $row .= '</tr>';
                echo $row;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

i am expecting value [image: like this] but its looping single id

Comment: If you enable errors - you will get a lot of undefined errors with `$offers['main']`, try instead of `if ($offers['main']==true || $offers['main']==1) {` - `if ($offers['main']??false) {`

Comment: @NigelRen tried but giving error.

Comment: What error? (it helps to work out what the problem is)

Comment: its showing same like before .[link](https://imgur.com/5RwCjIN) but not showing like expecting . why its looping id 3-4 times?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with having 3 different `if (\strcasecmp($offers['label']...` lines, each with an `else` which shows `NO DATA`

Comment: I am not sure. but i need those 3 specific if condition to show their data . i am just stuck